# ¿Como puedo hacer para enviar datos del servidor al cliente sin tener la web abierta?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backend

Tengo una web que consume datos de MySQL, en lo cual la web necesita tener sus últimos datos en tiempo real. Los datos primero pasan por SQL Server, pero no puedo tocar esa BD, así que cree un archivo PHP que agarra esos datos y me los inserta en MySQL. El tema es que ese archivo llamado `traspaso.php` funciona únicamente cuando está abierto el `index.php` (donde se muestran los datos). Funciona así porque tengo un JS asociado al `index.php`. Se que es un tema de backend, pero no le encuentro la vuelta de cómo resolverlo o que debo investigar para poder hacerlo bien, Y no tener que acceder al `index.php` para que me haga el traspaso de datos. Alguna sugerencia?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function changeNumber() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "traspaso.php",
});
}
setInterval(changeNumber, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Si eso debe correr en segundo plano, no debería depender de un script PHP que ejecutes desde un navegador. Podrías programar la ejecución del script PHP en el OS del servidor, por ejemplo.

Comment: Busca información relacionada con _cronjobs con `php` en el sistema operativo de tu servidor_.

Comment: Probe con las tareas programadas, funciona, abre el archivo que necesito. Pero antes de ponerlo en segundo plano, lo estuve ejecutando normal, para que lo abra y me muestre, pero siempre me da la opción, de con que navegador quiero ejecutarlo. No puedo saltar esa parte. Alguna idea de cómo evitar eso?